# How to make ctx.linewidth not influence previous drawed lines

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am writing a simple painting tool with HTML and JavaScript.

It allows users to choose the brush with different sizes through a slider. When the value of the slider changes, it changes ctx.lineWidth to realize it.

However, when the ctx.lineWidth changes, old strokes will change its width too. I want all the old stroke to maintain their size. Is there any solution?

The code of the canvas is as follow:

```
    function brush(){
        var el = document.getElementById('canvas');
        el.lineJoin = el.lineCap = 'round';
        var ctx = el.getContext('2d');
        var isDrawing;
        el.onmousedown = function(e) {
            isDrawing = true;
            var bounds = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
            x = e.pageX - bounds.left - scrollX;  
            y = e.pageY - bounds.top - scrollY;   
            ctx.moveTo(x, y);
        };

        el.onmousemove = function(e) {
            if (isDrawing) {
                console.log(el.lineWidth)
                var bounds = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
                x = e.pageX - bounds.left - scrollX;  
                y = e.pageY - bounds.top - scrollY;   
                ctx.lineTo(x, y);
                ctx.stroke();
            }
        };

        el.onmouseup = function() {
            isDrawing = false;
            };
    }
```

The code of the onchange function of the slider is as follows:

```
function adjust_size(){
        var value = document.getElementById('slider').value
        document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d').lineWidth = value
    }
```

Comment: You need to close the current path and begin a new one whenever the line width changes afaik.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `onmousedown` handler use `ctx.beginPath();` to start a new path,

then in `onmouseup` handler use `ctx.closePath()` to close it

ex:

```
        el.onmousedown = function(e) {
            isDrawing = true;
            ctx.beginPath();
            var bounds = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
            x = e.pageX - bounds.left - scrollX;  
            y = e.pageY - bounds.top - scrollY;   
            ctx.moveTo(x, y);
        };
        el.onmouseup = function() {
            ctx.closePath();
            isDrawing = false;
        };
```

Comment: ctx.closePath does not "end" a path definition. It does lineTo last entry point in the path, so that it becomes an *enclosed* path.

Comment: It works, thank you so much.